# I can't find my text in Unity no matter what I do

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to Unity and am trying to create a score for my game, but the text appears extremely far from the position where my game is set. I changed the coordinates from my text to the same coordinates where my game is set. I tried changing the font size, but it didn't help either.

[image: screenshot from the score inspector]

[image: screenshot from the player inspector]

Comment: Just out of interest - completely unrelated: You know there are two `Player` components on your object right? Regarding the text, what happens if you double click it in the hierarchy? Have in mind that the Canvas is in **pixel space** so UI will just appear **huge** in your scene view

Comment: In geeral I would rather recommend `TextMeshPro` and then if you want them to be worldspace use a `World Space` canvas instead of `Screen Space Overlay` and simply nest it under your player -> will move along with your player

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can I  directly convert my text into TextMeshPro, or do I need to make a whole new text for that?